# onError Sequence not triggered if DSS throws ERROR while execution in WSo2 EI 6.4.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

There is `DSS call` inside `Sequence` on every Iteration by using `Iterator`. This `DSS` will insert data to Database Table.

Sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="PushData_Seq" onError="Failure_Sequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="*********PushData_Seq" value="is called **********"/>
    </log>
  
    <!--  Iterate over JSON Array Elements -->
    <iterate expression="$body//rows" id="BigQID">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                <property expression="//f[1]/v/text()" name="Name" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="//f[2]/v/text()" name="Age" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                
                <!--  Frame payload for DSS Call -->
                <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:data_insert_op"/>
                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format>
                        <Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                            <Body>
                                <data_insert_op xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                                    <Name>$1</tenant>
                                    <Age>$2</source>
                                </data_insert_op>
                            </Body>
                        </Envelope>
                    </format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Name')"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Age')"/>
                        
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                <!--  calling DSS to push data -->
                <call>
                    <endpoint>
                        <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/services/test_DSS/data_insert_op">
                            <timeout>
                                <duration>60000</duration>
                            </timeout>
                            <suspendOnFailure>
                                <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                                <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
                                <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                            </suspendOnFailure>
                            <markForSuspension>
                                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                            </markForSuspension>
                        </http>
                    </endpoint>
                </call>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
    <property name="result" scope="default">
        <result xmlns=""/>
    </property>
    <!--  Aggregate for collecting DSS response in order to identify target updated row count -->
    <aggregate id="BigQID">
        <completeCondition>
            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete aggregateElementType="root" enclosingElementProperty="result" expression="$body/*[1]">
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="ON Aggregate SEQ" value="called***"/>
                <property expression="fn:count(//*[local-name()='UpdatedRowCount'])" name="*********BigQueryETL-TargetCount:: "/>
            </log>
        </onComplete>
    </aggregate>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="fn:concat('The data_push is Completed and sync_end_time is: ',get-property('SYSTEM_DATE','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))" name="data_push INFO: "/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

- added `onError="Failure_Sequence"` to the sequence, So when failure occurs, this `Failure_Sequence` will get triggered.
- added `FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT` property also inside iterator to trigger `Failure_Sequence`

Some sort of failure happened during DSS operation like below.

```
{org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver} -  Error in in-out message receiver
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': ERROR: value too long for type character varying(15)
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: Test_DSS
Location: /home/wso2carbon/wso2ei-6.4.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1679035873865BigQuery-ETL_CAR_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.car/Test_DSS_1.0.0/Test_DSS-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: data_insert_op
Current Params: {Name=iCMP-Engineering-1, Age=20}
Nested Exception:-
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(15)


    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:359)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:57)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:383)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery':
```

I know this ERROR is related to character length of column specific one, if we increase this limit, this could be resolved.

**Updated: - DSS Response via tryitout tool**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns589="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <soapenv:Code>
                <soapenv:Value>axis2ns589:DATABASE_ERROR</soapenv:Value>
            </soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Reason>
                <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dev_table_test_pkey"
  Detail: Key (dev_id)=(Engineering-1) already exists.
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: WSO2_ZCloud_test_DSS
Location: /home/wso2carbon/wso2ei-6.4.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1679061962717BigQuery-ETL_CAR_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.car/WSO2_ZCloud_test_DSS_1.0.0/WSO2_ZCloud_test_DSS-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: dev_inventory_insert_op
Current Params: {dev_name=Engineering-1, dev_id=Engineering-1, }
Nested Exception:-
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dev_table_test_pkey"
  Detail: Key (dev_id)=(Engineering-1) already exists.

</soapenv:Text>
            </soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Detail>
                <axis2ns588:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns588="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                    <axis2ns588:current_params>{dev_name=Engineering-1, dev_id=Engineering-1, }</axis2ns588:current_params>
                    <axis2ns588:source_data_service>
                        <axis2ns588:data_service_name>WSO2_ZCloud_test_DSS</axis2ns588:data_service_name>
                        <axis2ns588:description>N/A</axis2ns588:description>
                        <axis2ns588:location>/home/wso2carbon/wso2ei-6.4.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1679061962717BigQuery-ETL_CAR_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.car/WSO2_ZCloud_test_DSS_1.0.0/WSO2_ZCloud_test_DSS-1.0.0.dbs</axis2ns588:location>
                        <axis2ns588:default_namespace>http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice</axis2ns588:default_namespace>
                    </axis2ns588:source_data_service>
                    <axis2ns588:ds_code>DATABASE_ERROR</axis2ns588:ds_code>
                    <axis2ns588:nested_exception>org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dev_table_test_pkey"
  Detail: Key (dev_id)=(Engineering-1) already exists.</axis2ns588:nested_exception>
                    <axis2ns588:current_request_name>dev_inventory_insert_op</axis2ns588:current_request_name>
                </axis2ns588:DataServiceFault>
            </soapenv:Detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My concern here is that, Even DSS throws ERROR why that `Failure_Sequence` call not happened. It should triggered right?

please share your thoughts on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should, I assume you are not getting a proper SOAP Fault from the DSS service.(WSO2 will not trigger Fault Sequence for HTTP errors) Can you verify that? Also, try isolating the Call and test it against the DSS response and see whether it's triggering the fault sequence.

On a different note, the way you have implemented the Iterate logic the Iteration will stop if an error occurs, I'm not sure whether that's the intended behavior. If not you can move the code in the Iterate to a separate named sequence and attach an onError sequence to this Sequence.

**Update**

Sample filter condition.

```xml
<filter regex="202|200" source="$axis2:HTTP_SC">
    <then></then>
    <else>
        <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE_LOG" scope="default" type="STRING" value="Error occured while executing the forder 2 link query"/>
        <sequence key="SEQ_Error_Handler"/>
    </else>
</filter>
```

Comment: Hi @ycr,
I have added DSS Response ERROR got via Tryitout Tool. As you said, "test it against the DSS response and see whether it's triggering the fault sequence"--> how can we do it? if one row leads to an issue, how to continue transaction on next iteration in iterator configuration. please share your suggestion

Comment: @Justin remove the iterate, hardcode the payload and send it to DSS. The message you shared looks like a SOAP Fault. What HTTP response code do you get?

Comment: @Justin As I mentioned indoor to continue processing move the Iterate Code to a separate names sequence and then attach a fault handler to that.

Comment: Hi @ycr, will check and let you know the status

Comment: Hi @ycr,
I have got 500 as Http status code from DSS when ERROR occurred by using expression=get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC').

Comment: Hi @ycr,

Placed iterator code to the seperate named sequence and onERROR also added. This is not triggering that fault sequence when ERROR happening inside Iterator

Comment: @Justin Have you set FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT property?

Comment: Yes, It is placed inside Iterator as the First line of each Iteration

Comment: @Justin Not sure why it's not detected as a SOAP Fault, but I normally handle the errors in the same flow with a Filter condition. Take a look at the update in the answer.

Comment: Hi @ycr, Thanks for suggestion, If i add this filter inside iteration post dss call, i should place <drop> as the last mediator in fault sequence right? otherwise for each iteration process will trigger fault sequence.

Comment: @Justin that depends on how you want o handle it. If you are aggregating all the responses, you can create a Fault Payload using something like the PL Factory and continue the flow, so fault message will be appended when Iterate completes. If you don't want to return anything you can add a drop and stop the flow.